# asp.net - Membership.GetUser(string) not returning User when it should

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

Developing a multi-tenant asp.net MVC webapp with EntityFramework. Using `System.Web.Security` `MembershipProvider` for user accounts.

In my `aspnet_Users` table, I have two Users. Each one is associated with a different application, and thus have different `ApplicationId`s in the table.

```
ApplicationId = 1xxxxx, User1
ApplicationId = 2xxxxx, User2
```

When I am currently signed in as `User1` on `User1`'s application, I call

```
MembershipUser validUser = Membership.GetUser(User2.UserName)
```

but validUser is returned as null.

I am looking at the table in the database, the user is there. I am passing it the correct username.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the `ApplicationId`'s for the 2 users being different, so while we are logged in as `User1`, it only searches for users matching `User1`'s `ApplicationId`?

However, I cannot figure out why it's returning null, or how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, if you are using application 1, the membership provider will only look for users that belong to application 1.  That's usually the goal of multi-tenancy.

Comment: well yeah i suppose that's my question, is there any way/how do i switch to searching for members in application 2 while currently in application 1?

Comment: Write a custom membership provider -- or if you just want search for users , write a method that calls the appropriate query to search your user's table.